# White space among the images in table HTML

Tags: html, css

I was creating an email signature by joining images using table tags in HTML. It's looking ok in desktop view. But in mobile view whitespaces come around the images. I used `display: block` style but it's not working.
here is an example HTML code. I will be very grateful for the solution.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>email_signature</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<style>
    img{
        display: block;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<!-- Save for Web Slices (EMS_1.psd) -->
<table id="Table_01" width="1000" height="336" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/T3tLTqDC/image-01.jpg" width="806" height="182" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/CKtRqhJ8/image-02.jpg" width="24" height="182" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/wM5MZhz5/image-03.jpg" width="31" height="182" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/qM0znZc1/image-04.jpg" width="27" height="182" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/4yRnWWDN/image-05.jpg" width="29" height="182" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/zBgVwsPc/image-06.jpg" width="83" height="182" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/tg71JZdy/image-07.jpg" width="806" height="32" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/44pYYTcK/image-08.jpg" width="24" height="32" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DygmcdBn/image-09.jpg width="31" height="32" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/x118pJ4H/image-10.jpg" width="27" height="32" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/RZpFkSkY/image-11.jpg" width="29" height="32" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/N0yMBhYj/image-12.jpg" width="83" height="32" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/DZLw4qSV/image-13.jpg" width="806" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/mr0rrd2N/image-14.jpg" width="24" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/GtRhFHD4/image-15.jpg" width="31" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/BbCZM45M/image-16.jpg" width="27" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MZ0GWmkV/image-17.jpg" width="29" height="122" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/rF8wzRcb/image-18.jpg" width="83" height="122" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
</html>
```

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6NuQ.png)

Comment: I've just ran your code and it doesn't do anything different in mobile view?

Comment: I don't know what exactly you want. But try css:

    td {
    font-size:0;
    }

Comment: also, you can use the style attribute to turn your img into blocks.

Comment: I have added a mobile view image of this html at the top. desktop view looks good but when i inspect it it mobile view whitespace added around every <td> tag.

Comment: Does border-collapse: collapse; on table element fix the problem?

Comment: yes, i also tried border-collapse:collapse. But same result in mobile view

Comment: why does it have to be all images. is it an assignment for you to arrange these pieces? I mean you can design a webpage like this rather than making images size for different sized displays.

Comment: also the reason for the white space is the td containers have more height and width  than the images. you should assign same height and width for containers and contents. use inspect and u can notice what i am telling. Also , different td containers have different width and heights corresponding to the images with in them. so you have to correct each and every container and image separately. its a lot of work.